# Specified named range does not exist

Tags: android, excel, excel-formula, apache-poi

In my android application I have an excel file in which there are some formulas. In one formula I'm referencing a fixed value of "Mileage" from other cell.

Please see  [image: this image]  for reference.

In the image the **AMOUNT** column contains the formula **(=IF(F10="",0,F10*Mileage))** in which Mileage is the name of cell **J1** and it's value is **0.485** as shown in top-left corner in the image.

So when I try to copy this excel file into another I get this error
`W/System.err: org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParseException: Specified named range 'Mileage' does not exist in the current workbook.`

Comment: When you copy that file, are you define Mileage as well?

Comment: @DavidGarcíaBodego How to do that?

Comment: Look for Name Manager. It should be an option on Excel for Android. I can not check it. If not, look on `https://support.google.com/docs/answer/63175?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en`

Comment: @DavidGarcíaBodego, Thanks, this is what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As DavidGarcíaBodego suggested, We need to look for Name manager. https://support.google.com/docs/answer/63175?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en&oco=0

If you are coping the excel you need to copy the named Range/cell as well. For more see https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#NamedRanges

This is how I am able to copy all the named range/cell in the sheet

```
for (int i = 0; i < workbookSource.getNumberOfNames(); i++) {
            Name namedCel4 = workbookDestination.createName();
            namedCel4.setNameName(workbookSource.getNameAt(i).getNameName());
            namedCel4.setRefersToFormula(workbookSource.getNameAt(i).getRefersToFormula());
        }
```